# Android User Interface Tool

Tags: android, interface

I want to learn if there is an easier way to create a UI for Android. For example, for web design, we can convert psd to html. For Android programming, is there a solution like that or a tool that we can use easily?

Comment: [Droiddraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Additionally, any automated tool to convert PSD to HTML will not end well for anything but the most simple layouts.  If you're talking about just using Photoshop as a layout design tool then you can use the same process with Android if you like. There's no technical limitation there.

ADT includes a visual editor, but I can't say it's very good. I'd highly recommend just learning the layout APIs and getting good at editing the XML.

**Update:**

It turns out that Google has recently provided a number of [stencils](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-design-v2-now-with-stencils.html) to help with this designing process. It's still not a UI editor, but it might help with sketching things out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I should learn XML well as far as I get.